# Find out if and when admin consent was given

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible to query the Graph API and find whether the directory administrator gave administrator consent for the application and when this was done?

If so, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 3):

You would have to query the *oauth2PermissionGrants*. To get them you will have to know the object id of the application's service principal in the target directory. That one you can get if you know the app's client id.

For example if I query `https://graph.windows.net/<tenant id>/servicePrincipals/6e56b47c-4c6e-40f5-aa95-16a0b1cb44fc/oauth2PermissionGrants` from the Azure AD Graph API:

```
{
  "odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/<tenant id>/$metadata#oauth2PermissionGrants",
  "value": [
    {
      "clientId": "6e56b47c-4c6e-40f5-aa95-16a0b1cb44fc",
      "consentType": "AllPrincipals",
      "expiryTime": "2017-12-19T09:25:32.3581755",
      "objectId": "fLRWbm5M9UCqlRagsctE_M7PF6398j5LkfWqCoLpQBI",
      "principalId": null,
      "resourceId": "ad17cfce-f2fd-4b3e-91f5-aa0a82e94012",
      "scope": "User.Read",
      "startTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see this particular service principal has been granted the User.Read scope on the Azure AD Graph API for **AllPrincipals**, which means admin consent. If it was individual user consent, consentType would be **Principal**, with the principalId set to the id of the user who gave the consent.

Note you can't know when the consent was given.